# Difference between Tensorflow's tf.keras.layers.Dense and PyTorch's torch.nn.Linear?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have a quick (and possibly silly) question about how Tensorflow defines its Linear layer. Within PyTorch, a Linear (or Dense) layer is defined as, y = x A^T + b where A and b are the weight matrix and bias vector for a Linear layer (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear)).

However, I can't precisely find an equivalent equation for Tensorflow! Is it the same as PyTorch or is it just y = x A + b ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tf.keras.layers.Dense` is defined here in the tensorflow source code:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1081

If you follow the references in its `call` function, it leads you to the definition of the operation used here, which is indeed a matrix multiplication of the inputs and weights plus a bias vector as expected:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a68c6117a1a53431e739752bd2ab8654dbe2534a/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/ops/core.py#L74

```
outputs = gen_math_ops.MatMul(a=inputs, b=kernel)
...
outputs = nn_ops.bias_add(outputs, bias)
```

Comment: So, the definition of the `kernel` variable is a weight matrix but of the opposite dimension of PyTorch's weight matrix? So, let's say I have A input features of batch size N, and B output features. The dimensionality of `kernel` would be [A, B] whereas in the case of PyTorch it'd be [B, A] (because there's a transpose applied to it?)

Comment: Yes they store the weights slightly differently (W.T vs W) but the result is still the same. PyTorch's representation is closer to the notation in text books. You can check this quickly by printing out the shape of the Linear/Dense weights in torch and tf.

Comment: In [line 1192](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1192) of the first link to the TF source code above, the weights in are initialised with `shape=[last_dim, self.units]` (N_feats, N_out) and in PyTorch [(source code link)](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L79), the weights are initialised with `Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))` (N_out, N_feats)

Comment: Alright, so for a linear layer of input x of shape (N_samp, N_feats) the output for TF would be matmul(x, A)  + b where A is (N_feats, N_out) and b is (N_out, ) and for PyTorch it's matmul(x, A^T) + b where A is now (N_out, N_feats) and b is (N_out, ). Alright, so it seems that the 2 libraries define their Linear layers differently! Thank you @Alex!

Answer (score 23):

If we set activation to `None` in the dense layer in `keras` API, then they are technically equivalent.

Tensorflow's

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., activation=None)
```

According to the [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/), more study [here](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/).

> activation: Activation function to use. If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).

And in PyTorch's [src](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear).

```
torch.nn.Linear
```

They are now equal at this point. A linear transformation to the incoming data: `y = x*W^T + b`. See the following more concrete equivalent implementation of these two. In `PyTorch`, we do

```
class Network(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(5, 30)
    def forward(self, state):
        return self.fc1(state)
```

or,

```
trd = torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 3, out_features = 30)
y = trd(torch.ones(5, 3))
print(y.size())
# torch.Size([5, 30])
```

Its equivalent `tf` implementation would be

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(5,), activation=None))
```

or,

```
tfd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(3,), activation=None)
x = tfd(tf.ones(shape=(5, 3)))
print(x.shape)
# (5, 30)
```

Comment: What I mean, in terms of difference, is purely with regards to the Linear Algebra of the operation. Rather than just the shape of the output Tensor. For example, it seems that Tensorflow's Dense layer is either y = xA + b or y = Ax + b and PyTorch's Linear layer is y = xA^T + b. Although, these give out the same shape their derivatives are different.

Comment: Oh, I see. The question title confused me.  It seems like you wanted to know how they're calculated behind. Alex's answer should ok for you.

Comment: Yes, I could've phrased it slightly better. But regardless, I just needed clarification of the Linear Algebra itself and how these Layers differ between Linears. The derivative is one example in how they differ ( as they're different linear algrabra operations ). I did state a 'guess' of what TF's Dense layer is and if it's the same. So, I might make an edit to the title if other people think it'll help with clarification! Thank you for the explanation of the TF's Dense layer though! :D